# Projective Dimension and Schanuel's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a (say, left) $R$-module of projective dimension $n$. According to *Noncommutative Noetherian Rings*, any projective resolution of $M$ can be terminated at length $n$, and this is proved using an extended version of Schanuel's lemma: if $$0\to K \to P_0 \to \dots \to P_n \to M \to 0$$ $$0\to K' \to P_0' \to \dots \to P_n' \to M \to 0$$ are exact sequences of $R$-modules with each $P_j$, $P_j'$ projective then $$K' \oplus P_0 \oplus P_1' \dots \simeq K \oplus P_0' \oplus P_1 \cdots$$ I surprisingly managed to prove Schanuel's lemma and the extended version stated above, but I don't know how to put the pieces together and prove the claim about projective resolutions. Any thoughts? (Note: I don't want a full solution, just a nice hint would be great.)

Comment: Do the dots in the sums (2nd equation) continue up to index n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The statement of the lemma is using the wrong $n$; you'll want to use it for $n-1$ rather than $n$ (so the $P$s go up to $P_{n-1}$).  If $M$ has projective dimension $n$, then it has some such resolution in which $K$ is projective.  Now what does this tell you about the $K'$ you get by truncating any other projective resolution?

Comment: I'm starting to think I misunderstood the statement that any projective resolution can be terminated at length $n$. Does it mean: a) if $0\to Q_m \to \dots \to Q_0 \to M \to 0$ is a projective resolution with $m \geq n$, then  $0\to Q_n \to \dots \to Q_0 \to M \to 0$ is also a projective resolution, or b) we can find $Q$ such that $0\to Q \to Q_{n-1} \to \dots \to Q_0 \to M \to 0$ is also a projective resolution

Comment: It means (b).  There are no modules for which (a) is true, since you could always take the direct sum of one resolution with an exact sequence that has a nonzero map from its $(n+1)$st term to its $n$th term.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance! No wonder proving a) was difficult...